# Trouble linking css stylesheet to html

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I'm having trouble linking my css style sheet to my html file. I believe everything is formatted correctly and when I open the html file in finder it gives the right output but when I run my webapp that opens it locally it doesn't work. I'm using sublime to edit.

Heres part of my index.html file and my css file.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Attack On Purdue Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="init_div">
        <h1>ATTTACK ON PURDUE</h1>
        <div>
            <p style="display: inline">Username:  </p>
            <input type="username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p style="display: inline">Password:  </p>
            <input type="password">
        </div>

        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
    </div>
    ...
```

styles.css:

```
#init_div {
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Edit:
Actually I think it has something to do with how I run it. I'm using node to run my index.js file and express to open up index.html

Heres a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwoD8.png) to it and my file paths:

Comment: example your web located on `localhost/test/` then try to access `localhost/test/styles.css`, do the styles loaded?

Comment: That should be working. Are you sure your `styles.css` is in the same directory as you `index.html`?

Comment: Are the styles.css and index.html in the same directory. If not you will need to provide a relative path to the styles.css

Comment: Yea they are in the same directory

Comment: Should be working then, double check the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set proper path of your css file in href tag.
You can set your css like this in your head tag:

```
<link href="/css/example.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: But if my css file is in the same directory as my html, I dont need to include any paths though just href="styles.css" should do right?

Comment: If they're in the same directory no you don't have to include paths

Comment: @Yash Joshi, I don't think you should be including the first slash. That will make it an absolute path. You should be using relative paths so that when you move the site from test to prod you don't have to update the paths if they do change ;)

Answer (score 0):

Include the relative path to your css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/css/folder/styles.css">
```